# Class methods not calling properly in inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a base class with two functions: the first calls the second:

```
template <class T, size_t s> class BaseClass {
    /*....*/
    void init() {
        /*Do general initialization.*/
        specificInitialization();
    }

    void specificInitialization() {
        /*Do BaseClass specific initialization.*/
    }


};
```

And in my derived class, I want to do the following:

```
template <class T, size_t s> class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<T,s> {
    /*....*/
    void specificInitialization() {
        /*Do DerivedClass specific initialization.*/
    }
};
```

However, when implementing a DerivedClass, the BaseClass specific initialization will be called. If I write the init() function also in the DerivedClass everything goes as desired.

What is the reason of this? I am inheriting but I have to rewrite common code anyway and I do not like that too much :(

Thank you!

Comment: Please post some more realistic code. Details are important, and you are missing many out with your pseudo-code.

Comment: Is the function `virtual`?

Comment: Why wouldn't the specific initialization be called in the base class? You need to make it virtual and override it if you want it not to be called. Or do you want it to be called?

Comment: Well, it was the virtual keyword. I do not know how to get the StackOverflow people: some complain about not realistic code, others about too complex code :) In fact, I acknowledge I summarized too much this code. @juanchopanza the code is now OK.

Comment: @JaviV you should try it keep it simple but it should at least compile.

Comment: @Simple I know, my fault! I wrote the answer so fast I didn't review it properly. Now it is OK. Thanks!

Comment: Simple code does not mean invalid code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably haven't declared the function `virtual` in the base class; only virtual functions can be overridden:

```
virtual void specificInitialization();
^^^^^^^
```

Certainly the code you've posted doesn't contain `virtual`; but it's also missing class keys and return values, and therefore can't be the code you're compiling and running. I can only guess what your real code looks like.

Comment: My fault! Actually I was missing virtual in other functions as well. Thank you very much!